# Convert String to CommaDelimitedList Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation

I have the following Cloudformation Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  serviceRoleArn:
    Type: String
    Description: The role that's used when the task is executed.
  AWSInstanceID:
    Type: String
  awsSSMMaintenanceWindowTargetId:
    Type: String
  awsSSMMaintenanceWindowId:
    Type: String
  automationSSMTaskRole:
    Type: String
  automationSSMTaskType:
    Type: String
  automationSSMTaskDescription:
    Type: String
  automationSSMTaskARN:
    Type: String

Resources:
  startInstanceTask:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTask'
    Properties:
      MaxErrors: "2"
      Description: !Ref "automationSSMTaskDescription"
      ServiceRoleArn:
        Ref: serviceRoleArn
      Priority: 1
      MaxConcurrency: "1"
      Targets:
      - Values:
        - !Ref "awsSSMMaintenanceWindowTargetId"
        Key: WindowTargetIds
      Name: !Ref "automationSSMTaskType"
      TaskArn: !Ref "automationSSMTaskARN"
      WindowId: !Ref "awsSSMMaintenanceWindowId"
      TaskType: "AUTOMATION"
      TaskInvocationParameters:
        MaintenanceWindowAutomationParameters:
          DocumentVersion: "$DEFAULT"
          Parameters:
            InstanceId:
              - !Ref AWSInstanceID
            AutomationAssumeRole:
              - Ref: automationSSMTaskRole
```

However, AWSInstanceID is converting to:

```
"InstanceId": ["i-0375357htn1a8ad40,i-0d0f0f724tytf4d37,i-0e61cc61hthf8c2b2"]
```

But this is not the format I want. How do I get the following output?

```
"InstanceId": [
    "i-0375357htn1a8ad40",
    "i-0d0f0f724tytf4d37",
    "i-0e61cc61hthf8c2b2"
]
```

I would like to convert from String to CommaDelimitedList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFormation has an intrinsic function called [Fn::Split](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html). Copied from the user guide:

> The following example splits a string at each vertical bar (|). The function returns ["a", "b", "c"].

```
!Split [ "|" , "a|b|c" ]
```

So in your case, I guess it translates to

```
!Split [ ",", !Ref AWSInstanceID ]
```

Alternatively, you could also try and specify the `AWSInstanceID` as a [CommaDelimitedList](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html?shortFooter=true#parameters-section-structure-properties) type, e.g.

```
Parameters:
  AWSInstanceID:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Parameters - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html):

> `List<AWS::EC2::Instance::Id>`
>
> An array of Amazon EC2 instance IDs, such as i-1e731a32, i-1e731a34.

So, try changing your Parameter from:

```
Type: String
```

to:

```
Type: List<AWS::EC2::Instance::Id>
```

Comment: That wasn't my question, I want to pass in a String and convert it to comma delimited list.

Comment: My suggestion is that it could take in a list to begin with, and then there's no need to convert anything.

Comment: it's not as simple as it seems unfortunately as I'm using terraform to pass in the parameter and there's no way to pass in comma delimited parameter via terraform

Comment: In that case, you would probably need to create a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) using AWS Lambda. See: [Lambda-Backed Custom Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54951224/174777)